# Docker build "Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'" apt-get fails to install anything

Tags: docker, apt-get

I've been trying to run Docker build on various files which previously worked before, which are now no longer working.

As soon as the Docker file included any line that was to install software it would fail with a message saying that the package was not found.

```
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor nodejs npm
```

The common message which showed up in the logs was

```
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Any idea why any software will not install?

Comment: this will happen when machine gets disconnected from the net ... I have seen that happen on linux laptop with a new docker install if I only issue  `newgrp docker` instead of doing a full log off then login after giving myself `sudo usermod -aG docker  myuserid` ... its an edge case for sure however it does happen

Comment: @ScottStensland This saved me! Rebooting my computer. Maybe you could add this as a full answer!

Comment: In my case, the external firewall of my provider was the culprit. Disabling it during `docker compose build` fixed the problem. I don't know which requests should be allowed.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

After much headache I found the answer. `Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'` can be fixed by making the following changes:

1. Uncomment the following line in `/etc/default/docker`
   `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"`
2. Restart the Docker service
   `sudo service docker restart`
3. Delete any images which have cached the invalid DNS settings.
4. Build again and the problem should be solved.

Credit goes to [Andrew SB](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/docker-on-ubuntu-14-04-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com)

Comment: you can also add --no-cache=true if you'd rather not do #3 above

Comment: Thanks @jschorr I didn't know about that command at the time. That's a better idea.

Comment: Does someone know where this `etc` file is located within OSX ?

Comment: If you used homebrew I believe it is in /usr/local/share/etc or maybe /usr/share/etc, but not at Mac to check. I always forget myself.

Comment: I just occurred to me you might have to edit they file in the boot2docker vm. Try running "boot2docker ssh" then check to see if the /etc/defaults/docker file is there.

Comment: This isn't working for me and I have no idea why. I've been fighting this on and off for weeks.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I looked and don't see a way to edit this config in boot2docker. It's possible the /etc/defaults/docker file needs to be manually created.

Comment: I'm running on linux mint so there is no boot2docker. /etc/default/docker is created and has the DOCKER_OPTS flag above. I've restarted the service, cleared out all images and containers but still nothing.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the stupid [docker-whale tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_four/) to work.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I would also try the --no-cache=true as mentioned above by jschorr. ex: `docker build --no-cache=true ...`

Comment: I ran `docker build --no-cache=true -t docker-whale .` but nothing different seems to have happened.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, using VMWare and Ubuntu15.04 as host. However, it does work on boot2docker.

Comment: I ran into this problem after updating docker-compose from 1.4.0 to 1.4.2 (on a Mac and VirtualBox). Restarting my computer solved it for me.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Did you manage to find an alternative solution? I'm becoming mad with the same issue

Comment: @rosysnake Nope, gave up. I'm not running across jobs that are using Docker anyway so I lost interest entirely.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn and @rosysnake, you might try adding the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as I describe in my answer. It's kinda frustrating to be hit with such a technical roadblock so early on! Corey, hopefully my fix will spark new interest ;)

Comment: Also fixed by resetting to factory installation on mac. Must have been that it was looking for 8.8.8.8 but I didn't have the defaults file listed in this answer, so I just reset it.

Comment: If none of the above works, use the `--network=host` option with the `docker build` commands, and `--net=host` for `docker run`.

Comment: After few days googling, still cannot fix the issue, I used ubuntu 18 on a Virtual box machine.

Comment: This was the solution for me (running on Ubuntu 20.02 @ WSL2 using native docker, *not* Docker Desktop for Windows). I fail at understand why I suddenly needed to do that although it earlier worked without the change.

Answer (score 276):

Uncommenting `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"` in `/etc/default/docker` as [Matt Carrier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873559/matt-carrier) suggested did **NOT** work for me. Nor did putting my corporation's DNS servers in that file. But, there's another way (read on).

First, let's verify the problem:

```
$ docker run --rm busybox nslookup google.com   # takes a long time
nslookup: can't resolve 'google.com'   # <--- appears after a long time
Server:    8.8.8.8
Address 1: 8.8.8.8
```

If the command appears to hang, but eventually spits out the error "can't resolve 'google.com'", then you have the same problem as me.

The `nslookup` command queries the DNS server 8.8.8.8 in order to turn the text address of 'google.com' into an IP address. Ironically, 8.8.8.8 is [Google's public DNS server](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/). If `nslookup` fails, ***public DNS servers like 8.8.8.8 might be blocked by your company*** (which I assume is for security reasons).

You'd think that adding your company's DNS servers to `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker` should do the trick, but for whatever reason, it didn't work for me. I describe what worked for me below.

**SOLUTION**:

On the host (I'm using Ubuntu 16.04), find out the primary and secondary DNS server addresses:

```
$ nmcli dev show | grep 'IP4.DNS'
IP4.DNS[1]:              10.0.0.2
IP4.DNS[2]:              10.0.0.3
```

Using these addresses, create a file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
$ sudo su root
# cd /etc/docker
# touch daemon.json
```

Put this in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{                                                                          
    "dns": ["10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3"]                                                                           
}
```

Exit from root:

```
# exit
```

Now restart docker:

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

**VERIFICATION**:

Now check that adding the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file allows you to resolve 'google.com' into an IP address:

```
$ docker run --rm busybox nslookup google.com
Server:    10.0.0.2
Address 1: 10.0.0.2
Name:      google.com
Address 1: 2a00:1450:4009:811::200e lhr26s02-in-x200e.1e100.net
Address 2: 216.58.198.174 lhr25s10-in-f14.1e100.net
```

**REFERENCES**:

I based my solution on an article by Robin Winslow, who deserves all of the credit for the solution. Thanks, Robin!

"Fix Docker's networking DNS config." Robin Winslow. Retrieved 2016-11-09. https://robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/

Comment: Nice write-up to say the least

Comment: I received an error, that the service can not be started after the changes.
This was because I modified the DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker and /etc/init.d/docker . Reverting the changes resolved the startup problem of the docker service

Comment: This worked for me (on a company network) while the accepted solution did not.

Comment: This worked for me as well while the accepted solution did not. I used nslookup to get my DNS server IP though not nmcli.

Comment: I can also verify this method worked for me, from within my corporate network.

Comment: If you add the DNS servers in the file `/etc/default/docker` file as `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 10.0.0.2 --dns 10.0.0.2 --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"`

This will also work.

Comment: perfect solution for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: As others have noted the accepted answer did not work for me, but this did.

Comment: I had the same issue it worked for me .
thanks.
can you just explain whats the reason for daemon.json?
what is it ?
a good link would be appreciated.

Comment: daemon.json works for me as well!  And you can check if your company has blocked 8.8.8.8 by this command `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` In my case it is so I got this error `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 17.04. After a fresh new docker installation, I wasn't being able to reach the internet from inside the containers.

Comment: did not work for me, I was missing the `docker-machine` https://docs.docker.com/machine/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for saving me from two days struggle! I use Ubuntu 16.04.4 and install the docker DEB from here https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_17.12.1~ce-0~ubuntu_amd64.deb. When I build an image the docker is stuck at "apt-get update". I try to modify the DNS in /etc/default/docker and comment dns=dnsmasq in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. However,neither of them   works. This answer is exactly  the solution to my problem! Thank you,dude!

Comment: this is the only working solution! I wonder why docker has this peculiarity, why it cannot work like every other application that does work without having to specify dns to it

Comment: so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50001940/311567)  is a less-hacky solution that will not have to be changed if those DNS ips change by net admins

Comment: I think the reason `/etc/default/docker` didn't work for some people is (quoting a comment from the file) `# THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD`

Comment: worked for me - added daemon.json file and restarted the docker , worked like charm

Comment: The university I work at blocks all DNS requests off the university's network for security reasons. I had to use this technique to set the DNS hosts for Docker to the local ones.

Comment: This did not solve my issue, I still have the problem 
`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

I am receiving this error once I connect through the VPN of my university. When I disconnect the VPN is still not working. It starts working again only if I restart my computer, which I think restarts the overall network architecture. I don't know why.

Comment: Just a note that this answer led me to fix the problem, but for me the fix turned out to be the _opposite_ of what is suggested:  My problem was that `/etc/docker/daemon.json` had a stale `"dns"` entry that was left over from an old install and was no longer valid.  My fix was to *remove* the incorrect `"dns"` entry in `daemon.json` and let docker default to importing the host's DNS configuration.

Comment: I faced this error:
** server can't find google.com: NXDOMAIN

*** Can't find google.com: No answer

Comment: For more robust help, i.e. for MacOS/X, add the { "dns": ["ip1", "ip2", ..."ipn"] } to your `$HOME/.docker/daemon.json` file

Answer (score 86):

I run into the same problem, but neither uncommenting */etc/default/docker* dns entries nor editing the */etc/resolv.conf* in the build container or the */etc/docker/daemon.json* helps for me.

But after I build with the option --network=host the resolving was fine again.

```
docker build --network=host -t my-own-ubuntu-like-image .
```

Maybe this will help someone again.

Comment: I've been getting a different error for a long time "Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (x.x.x.x). - connect (111: Connection refused)" and found that using the --network=host has now fixed my problem

Comment: After tons of troubleshooting this is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I believe that [Matt Carrier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24991137/158755) is the correct solution for this problem. However, after implementing it, I still observed the same behavior: `could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'`.

This led me to eventually find that the network I was connected to was blocking public DNS. The solution to this problem was to configure my Docker container to use the same name server that my host (the machine from which I was running Docker) was using.

**How I triaged:**

1. Since I was working through the Docker documentation, I already had an example image installed on my machine. I was able to start a new container to run that image and create a new bash session in that container: `docker run -it docker/whalesay bash`
2. Does the container have an Internet connection?: `ping 172.217.4.238` (google.com)
3. Can the container resolve hostnames? `ping google.com`

In my case, the first `ping` resulted in responses, the second did not.

**How I fixed:**

Once I discovered that DNS was not working inside the container, I verified that I could duplicate the same behavior on the host. `nslookup google.com` resolved just fine on the host. But, `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` or `nsloookup google.com 8.8.4.4` timed out.

Next, I found the name server(s) that my host was using by running `nm-tool` (on Ubuntu 14.04). In the vein of fast feedback, I started up the example image again, and added the IP address of the name server to the container's resolv.conf file: `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf`. Once saved, I attempted the ping again (`ping google.com`) and this time it worked!

Please note that the changes made to the container's resolv.conf are not persistent and will be lost across container restarts. In my case, the more appropriate solution was to add the IP address of my network's name server to the host's `/etc/default/docker` file.

Comment: Concrete commands to get the addresses name servers: `nmcli device show <interfacename> | grep IP4.DNS` (Ubuntu >= 15) and `nmcli dev list iface <interfacename> | grep IP4` (Ubuntu < 15). Credit: [Marty Fried](http://askubuntu.com/a/152610/94548).

Comment: This is a more extensive answer. I always have issues when I switch to my office network or when there are network changes. Adding your company's DNS server fixes the lookup issue.

Comment: Very instructional! It's rare to find answers that show you how to verify the problem, then provide a fix (and verify the fix works). Great troubleshooting!

Comment: Hey, can you help me out? I am having same issue but my host is a windows machine where I am trying to run my docker container and trying to configure the Ubuntu image there. When you talk of name server here, does it mean the DNS server address of my windows machine? And in that too, will it be the primary one or the secondary one?

Comment: This is the exact problem I faced as my organization blocked the public DNS and setting the organization's DNS in /etc/default/docker under DOCKER_OPTS worked and issue resolved. All hail this answer...

Answer (score 7):

After adding local dns ip to default docker file it started working for me... please find the below steps...

```
$ nm-tool # (will give you the dns IP)
```

> DNS : 172.168.7.2

```
$ vim /etc/default/docker # (uncomment the DOCKER_OPTS and add DNS IP)
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 172.168.7.2 --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

$ rm `docker ps --no-trunc -aq` # (remove all the containers to avoid DNS cache)

$ docker rmi $(docker images -q) # (remove all the images)

$ service docker restart #(restart the docker to pick up dns setting)
```

Now go ahead and build the docker... :)

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who is also having this problem, I solved my problem by editing the `/etc/default/docker` file, as suggested by other answers and questions. However I had no idea what IP to use as the DNS.

It was only after a while I figured out I had to run `ifconfig docker` on the host to show the IP for the docker network interface.

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 02:42:69:ba:b4:07  
          inet end.: 172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Masc:255.255.0.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::42:69ff:feba:b407/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:8433 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:9876 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:484195 (484.1 KB) TX bytes:24564528 (24.5 MB)
```

It was **`172.17.0.1`** in my case. Hope this helps anyone who is also having this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified the way in which you edited your docker file

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04: `ifconfig docker0`

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add a late response for anyone coming across this issue from search engines.

**Do NOT do this:** I used to have an option in /etc/default/docker to set `iptables=false`. This was because ufw didn't work (everything was opened even though only 3 ports were allowed) so I blindly followed the answer to this question: [Uncomplicated Firewall (UFW) is not blocking anything when using Docker](https://askubuntu.com/a/652572) and [this, which was linked in the comments](https://svenv.nl/unixandlinux/dockerufw)

I have a very low understanding of iptables rules / nat / routing in general, hence why I might have done something irrational.

Turns out that I've probably misconfigured it and killed DNS resolution inside my containers. When I ran an interactive container terminal: `docker run -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash`

I had these results:

```
root@6b0d832700db:/# ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com

root@6b0d832700db:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search online.net
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

root@6b0d832700db:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=1.76 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=1.72 ms
```

Reverting all of my ufw configuration (before.rules), disabling ufw and removing iptables=false from /etc/default/docker restored the DNS resolution functionality of the containers.

I'm now looking forward to re-enable ufw functionality by following [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#enable-ufw-forwarding) instead.

Answer (score 6):

I found [this answer](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/wiki/Common-Issues-and-Fixes) after some Googleing. I'm using Windows, so some of the above answers did not apply to my file system.

Basically run:

```
docker-machine ssh default
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Which just overwrites the existing nameserver used with `8.8.8.8` I believe. It worked for me!

Based on some comments, you may have to be root. To do that, issue `sudo -i`.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows 10, because `ssh` doesn't exist?

Comment: @Seanny123 it's been a while since I've done anything with this, but I was on Windows 10 as well. I may have been using the older [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) at the time? Otherwise you may need to [enable the Windows SSH Client](https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands/). I'd probably start with that.

Comment: this worked out for me after I became root, to do that, issue `sudo -i` once you are in

Answer (score 5):

I have struggled for some time with this now as well, but here it is what solved it for me on `Ubuntu 16.04 x64`. I hope it saves someone's time, too.

1. In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:
   comment out
   `#dns=dnsmasq`
2. Create (or modify) `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```

3. Restart docker with:
   `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: Seems to be same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/40516974/2308683

Comment: Actually not. The fix in NetworkManager.conf made a difference for my case.

Comment: I highly doubt disabling dnsmasq system wide is the best solution specifically for Docker

Comment: I am sharing what worked for me after fighting 2 days with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, and tried the steps mentioned, but seems none works until refresh the network settings.

The steps:

1. As mentioned, add `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --ip-masq=true"` to `/etc/default/docker`.
2. Manually flush the PREROUTING table contents using the `iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING` . After running this, restart docker and it will initialize the nat table with the new IP range.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue for me (on Ubuntu Xenial).

- `docker run --dns ...` for containers worked.
- Updating docker daemon options for `docker build` (docker-compose etc.) did not work.

After analyzing the docker logs (`journalctl -u docker.service`) if found some warning about bad resolvconf applied.

Following that i found that our corporate nameservers were added to the network interfaces but not in resolvconf.

Applied this solution [How do I configure my static DNS in interfaces? (askubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/a/316175/408491), i.e. adding nameservers to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`

After updating resolvconf (or reboot).

`bash
docker run --rm busybox nslookup google.com`

worked instantly.

All my docker-compose builds are working now.

Answer (score 3):

Before spending too much time on any of the other solutions, **simply restart Docker** and try again.

Solved the problem for me, using Docker Desktop for Windows on Windows 10.

Comment: Restarting it with admin rights solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue today, I just added line below to /etc/default/docker

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 172.18.20.13 --dns 172.20.100.29 --dns 8.8.8.8"
```

and then I restarted my Laptop.

In my case restarting docker daemon is not enough for me, I have to restart my Laptop to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, firewall was the issue. Disabling it for the moment solved the issue. I use `nftables`. Stopping the service did the trick.

```
sudo systemctl stop nftables.service
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, since my containers were in a cloud environment the MTU of the interfaces were not usual 1500 and was like 1450, so I had to configure my docker daemon to set the MTU to 1450 for containers.

```
{  
"mtu": 1454 
}
```

look at this : https://mlohr.com/docker-mtu/

Answer (score 1):

With the recent updates, the following line in (`/etc/docker/daemon.json`) was the cause of the issue:

```
{
    "bridge": "none"
}
```

Remove it, and restart the docker service with: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

OS (`Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`) and Docker (`version 20.10.11, build dea9396`)

Answer (score 1):

When running docker build use either of the below options

```
--network=host
--network=bridge
--network={your_own}   #ensure that driver is either bridge or host
```

The default network value doesn't allow to connect to external network.

```
  --network string          Set the networking mode for the RUN instructions during build (default "default")
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system (`macOS High Sierra 10.13.6` with `Docker 2.1.0.1`) this was due to a corporate proxy.

I solved this by two steps:

1. Manually configure proxy settings in `Preferences>Proxies`
2. Add the same settings to your config.json inside `~/.docker/config.json` like:

   ```
    "proxies":
   {
     "default":
     {
       "httpProxy": "MYPROXY",
       "httpsProxy": "MYPROXY",
       "noProxy": "MYPROXYWHITELIST"
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have `dnsmasq` in my system for dns resolution that had the nameservers to resolve the URL. Docker copies `/etc/resolv.conf` of the host system as it is into the container's `/etc/resolv.conf` and thus didn't have the right nameservers. From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services):

> By default, a container inherits the DNS settings of the host, as
> defined in the `/etc/resolv.conf` configuration file.

Adding the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` of the host fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this for a very silly reason. Several weeks ago I configured docker to send traffic through a proxy, which I since removed and forgot to tell docker to stop using it.

It might be worth checking to see if you did something similar.

Go to `~/.docker/config.json` and check that there's nothing [like this](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client) in there:

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
     "httpsProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com,127.0.0.0/8"
   }
 }
}
```

If there is, try removing it, restarting docker deamon/desktop, and trying again. That solved for me.

Small side note: after closing and Docker Desktop (on mac) it wouldn't reopen and I had to force quit it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71861493/5783745) but after that everything worked as expected).