# Install pip in docker

Tags: python, docker, pip

I'm not able to install pip in Docker.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y git curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql python3.4 python-pip
```

When building, I get:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 109.6 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> b549a9959a66
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 84577471562c
Step 3 : RUN apt-get install -y git curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql python3.4 python-pip
 ---> Running in 49252a6d0eb1
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
python3.4 is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-bin apache2-data binutils build-essential ca-certificates cpp
  cpp-4.8 dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.8 gcc gcc-4.8 git-man krb5-locales
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl
  libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libasan0
  libasn1-8-heimdal libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcloog-isl4 libcurl3
  libcurl3-gnutls libdpkg-perl libedit2 liberror-perl libfakeroot
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-4.8-dev libgmp10 libgomp1 libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libidn11 libisl10 libitm1
  libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  libldap-2.4-2 libmcrypt4 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmysqlclient18 libpython-stdlib
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libquadmath0 libroken18-heimdal
  librtmp0 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libstdc++-4.8-dev
  libtimedate-perl libtsan0 libwind0-heimdal libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6
  libxcb1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxml2 libxmuu1 linux-libc-dev lsof make
  manpages manpages-dev mysql-common openssh-client openssl patch php5-cli
  php5-common php5-json php5-readline psmisc python python-chardet
  python-chardet-whl python-colorama python-colorama-whl python-distlib
  python-distlib-whl python-html5lib python-html5lib-whl python-minimal
  python-pip-whl python-pkg-resources python-requests python-requests-whl
  python-setuptools python-setuptools-whl python-six python-six-whl
  python-urllib3 python-urllib3-whl python-wheel python2.7 python2.7-minimal
  python3-pkg-resources rsync sgml-base ssl-cert xauth xml-core xz-utils
Suggested packages:
  www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom ufw
  apache2-utils binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-4.8-locales debian-keyring
  g++-multilib g++-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc libstdc++6-4.8-dbg gcc-multilib
  autoconf automake1.9 libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-4.8-multilib
  libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg
  libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg gettext-base git-daemon-run
  git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch
  git-bzr git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn php-pear glibc-doc krb5-doc krb5-user
  libmcrypt-dev mcrypt libsasl2-modules-otp libsasl2-modules-ldap
  libsasl2-modules-sql libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
  libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal libstdc++-4.8-doc make-doc man-browser
  ssh-askpass libpam-ssh keychain monkeysphere ed diffutils-doc
  php5-user-cache python-doc python-tk python-genshi python-lxml
  python-distribute python-distribute-doc python2.7-doc binfmt-support
  python3-setuptools openssh-server sgml-base-doc openssl-blacklist debhelper
Recommended packages:
  ssh-client python-dev-all
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data binutils build-essential ca-certificates
  cpp cpp-4.8 curl dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.8 gcc gcc-4.8 git git-man
  krb5-locales libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libasan0 libasn1-8-heimdal
  libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcloog-isl4 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls
  libdpkg-perl libedit2 liberror-perl libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libgcc-4.8-dev libgmp10 libgomp1 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal
  libhx509-5-heimdal libidn11 libisl10 libitm1 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1
  libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libmcrypt4
  libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmysqlclient18 libpython-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal
  libpython2.7-stdlib libquadmath0 libroken18-heimdal librtmp0 libsasl2-2
  libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libstdc++-4.8-dev libtimedate-perl
  libtsan0 libwind0-heimdal libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6
  libxext6 libxml2 libxmuu1 linux-libc-dev lsof make manpages manpages-dev
  mysql-common openssh-client openssl patch php5 php5-cli php5-common
  php5-json php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-readline psmisc python python-chardet
  python-chardet-whl python-colorama python-colorama-whl python-distlib
  python-distlib-whl python-html5lib python-html5lib-whl python-minimal
  python-pip python-pip-whl python-pkg-resources python-requests
  python-requests-whl python-setuptools python-setuptools-whl python-six
  python-six-whl python-urllib3 python-urllib3-whl python-wheel python2.7
  python2.7-minimal python3-pkg-resources rsync sgml-base ssl-cert xauth
  xml-core xz-utils
0 upgraded, 130 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 61.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 213 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libroken18-heimdal amd64 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libasn1-8-heimdal amd64 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

.
.
.

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main python2.7 amd64 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libroken18-heimdal_1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libasn1-8-heimdal_1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb5support0_1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/ssl-cert/ssl-cert_1.0.33_all.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql python3.4 python-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Having read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34145676/1040915), I tried adding the line `RUN "sh" "-c" "echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf"` - the error this time is:

```
...
...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package php5-mcrypt
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git curl apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql python3.4 python-pip' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What am I doing wrong? I've seen some claims that I should try a different version of Ubuntu, but switching to 13.1 didn't change anything.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

While [T. Arboreus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36611537/4298200) might fix the issues with resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com', I think the last error you're getting says that it doesn't know about the packages `php5-mcrypt` and `python-pip`.
Nevertheless, the reduced Dockerfile of you with just these two packages worked for me (using Debian 8.4 and Docker 1.11.0), but I'm not quite sure if that could be the case because my host system is different than yours.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    php5-mcrypt \
    python-pip
```

However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587528/5755166) you should think about installing the `python3-pip` package instead of the `python-pip` package when using Python 3.x.

Furthermore, to make the `php5-mcrypt` package installation working, you might want to add the universe repository like it's shown [right here](https://askubuntu.com/a/483188). I had trouble with the `add-apt-repository` command missing in the Ubuntu Docker image so I installed the package `software-properties-common` at first to make the command available.

Splitting up the statements and putting `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` into one `RUN` command is also recommended [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Oh and by the way, you actually don't need the `-y` flag at `apt-get update` because there is nothing that has to be confirmed automatically.

## Finally:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    curl \
    git \
    libapache2-mod-php5 \
    php5 \
    php5-mcrypt \
    php5-mysql \
    python3.4 \
    python3-pip
```

Remark: The used versions (e.g. of Ubuntu) might be outdated in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm on Mac OS X (10.11.4), if that makes any difference (though I thought the whole point of Docker was that it ran independently of the underlying system? I'm quite new to this, so I might be wrong...). I'll try your suggestions now.

Comment: @CharlieParker `apt-get update` updates the locally cached information about packages in the repository (e.g. where to download them or which versions are available). Without, you could e.g. run into installing outdated packages. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/337198/is-sudo-apt-get-update-mandatory-before-every-package-installation
I also edited the `apt-get update` and the `apt-get install` to be in one `RUN` command as recommended here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: apt-get update is required to prevent caching when building the container, see docker docs. -y is to prevent the prompt that says 'yes', download, to prevent errors on build

Comment: This will not install a specific version. It is wrong answer I think. Need specific versions. So pick stale old python, then how to install pip for that stale old python?

Answer (score 18):

This command worked fine for me:

```
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Uncomment the following line in /etc/default/docker
   DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
2. Restart the Docker service sudo service docker restart
3. Delete any images which have cached the invalid DNS settings.
4. Build again and the problem should be solved.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991136/docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-a).

Comment: No luck - there's no file `/etc/default/docker` on my system (Mac OS X)

Comment: Sorry, tapped out on thisone

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the DNS settings of the Docker daemon. You can edit (or create) the configuration file at `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the dns key, as

```
{
    "dns": ["your_dns_address", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

In the example above, the first element of the list is the address of your DNS server. The second item is the Google’s DNS which can be used when the first one is not available.

Before proceeding, save daemon.json and restart the docker service.

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Once fixed, retry to run the build command.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the Alpine Linux containers, e.g. `python:2.7-alpine`. They offer `pip` out of the box (and have a smaller footprint, but beware of [possible python problems](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/)).

Answer (score -1):

### odoo ## odoo

docker exec -it (id conatianer odoo) /bin/bash

after installed : pip install dropbox , pip install pyncclient, pip install nextcloud-api-wrapper , pip install boto3 ,   pip install paramiko

for module auto_database_backup

Comment: Please format your answer so that the code is contained in codeblocks. Currently it is hard to follow. Also, given that this question has an accepted answer which has been verified by the SO community, it is expected that you add some text explaining how your solution differs from all the other answers. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can try: `sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev`