# Install PIP3 and PYTHON3.7 on Docker Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker, pip, python-3.7

I have to install `Python3.7` and `pip3` for Python3.7 on my Docker Ubuntu18.04. I can install the `3.7`, but I cannot get rid of `pip3` for `Python3.6`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# ...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        software-properties-common
    RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3.7 \
        python3-pip
    RUN python3.7 -m pip install pip
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3-distutils \
        python3-setuptools
```

and I have

```
root@ef0c924ba7fa:/tornado_api# python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.3
root@ef0c924ba7fa:/tornado_api# pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

while it should be `pip3` under `/usr/lib/python3.7/`

Currently, I get

```
root@ef0c924ba7fa:/tornado_api# which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
root@ef0c924ba7fa:/tornado_api# readlink $(which pip3)
root@ef0c924ba7fa:/tornado_api#
```

Comment: What does `which pip3` return?

Comment: @MTCoster updated answer with details.

Comment: Thanks! How about `readlink $(which pip3)`?

Comment: I get anything from `readlink $(which pip3)`. What is supposed to do? get the symlink?

Comment: [`readlink`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) should follow a symlink if there is one

Comment: got it, there is no symlink basically for `pip3` I guess.

Comment: You won't be able to get rid of `pip==9.0.1` for Python 3.6 in Debian/Ubuntu using `apt`, see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3-defaults/+bug/1800723). `python3-pip` installs `pip` for `python3`, which happens to be Python 3.6, and `python3.7` doesn't have its own `pip` pendant.

Comment: @hoefling thank you! Is out there a solution or a workaround?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 has python 3.7 as the default version. You could upgrade?

Comment: @loretoparisi IMO Python 3 on Debian/Ubuntu is a mess right now. You can't have a useful Python 3.7 installation without pulling at least the base Python 3.6 stuff. The cleanest way I see right now for a 3.6-minimal image is not to touch `python3-pip` at all and resort to `get-pip.py`: `apt install python3.7 curl python3-distutils && curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python3.7 get-pip.py`.

Comment: If you don't need any complex installations, you can simply use a `python:3.7` docker image as base. It is anyways a linux based image with all the python requirements installed.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this has gone stale, nevertheless, I was wondering whether by simply doing a `python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# ...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        software-properties-common
    RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3.7 \
        python3-pip
    RUN python3.7 -m pip install pip
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3-distutils \
        python3-setuptools
    RUN python3.7 -m pip install pip --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try '`sudo apt purge pip3`' or '`sudo apt-get purge pip3`'
If that does not work then try uninstalling pip3 *with* pip3. (I'm not that sure how)

My next thing to try is to update pip3 with '`pip3 install pip3`' (I think)

If those don't work then I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any complex installations, you can simply use a `python:3.7` docker image as base. It is anyways a linux based image with all the python requirements installed.

Explore different python images and usage: https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Eg.:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./your-daemon-or-script.py" ]
```

Or if your requirement needs the same ubuntu image used, you can refer to this answer: [Install pip in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36611052/8438982)

Answer (score 1):

Just reinstall

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.7 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

This work fine for me...

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common gcc && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.8 python3-distutils python3-pip python3-apt
```