# Upgrading Python version for running and creating custom container for Sagemaker Endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sagemaker

[UPDATED] We are currently working on creating a Multi-Arm Bandit model for sign up optimization using the Build Your Own workflow that can be found here (basically substituting the model for our own):

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own

Our project directory is set up as:
[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwaIQ.png)

The issue is that I added some code including the dataclasses library that is only available since Python 3.7, and our project seems to keep using 3.6, causing a failure when running the Cloud Formation set up. The error in our Cloudwatch Logs is:

```
2021-03-31T11:04:11.077-05:00 Copy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/program/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import predictor as myapp
  File "/opt/program/predictor.py", line 9, in <module>
    from model_contents.model import MultiArmBandit, BanditParameters
  File "/opt/program/model_contents/model.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker worker.init_process() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process self.load_wsgi() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi self.callable = self.load() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load return self.load_wsgiapp() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp return util.import_app(self.app_uri) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app mod = importlib.import_module(module) File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/opt/program/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module> import predictor as myapp File "/opt/program/predictor.py", line 9, in <module> from model_contents.model import MultiArmBandit, BanditParameters File "/opt/program/model_contents/model.py", line 7, in <module> from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict

    2021-03-31T11:04:11.077-05:00

Copy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'
```

Our updated Dockerfile is:

```
# This is a Python 3 image that uses the nginx, gunicorn, flask stack
# for serving inferences in a stable way.

FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Retrieves information about what packages can be installed
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         python3-pip \
         python3.8 \
         python3-setuptools \
         nginx \
         ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set python 3.8 as default
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 1
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1

# Here we get all python packages.
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install numpy boto3 flask gunicorn

# Set some environment variables. PYTHONUNBUFFERED keeps Python from buffering our standard
# model_output stream, which means that logs can be delivered to the user quickly. PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
# keeps Python from writing the .pyc files which are unnecessary in this case. We also update
# PATH so that the train and serve programs are found when the container is invoked.

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"
ENV PYTHONPATH /model_contents

# Set up the program in the image
COPY bandit/ /opt/program/
WORKDIR /opt/program/

RUN chmod +x /opt/program/serve && chmod +x /opt/program/train
LABEL git_tag=$GIT_TAG
```

I'm not sure if the nginx.conf file defaults to Py 3.6 so I want to make sure that it's not a big hassle to upgrade to Py 3.7 or 3.8 without many changes.

Comment: Found a question that might be similar but not exactly sure how to update this Dockerfile for that use case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371949/how-to-install-python-3-7-and-pip-from-dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the Dockerfile after it install Python3.8 using `apt-get` with the following `RUN` commands

```
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 1
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
```

The first `RUN` command will link `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3.8` and the second one will link `/usr/bin/python3` to `/usr/bin/python3.8`

Comment: Thanks! So are you meaning that I should add that after the `RUN apt-get` or replace them? I modified Dockerfile above:

Comment: Yeah you should try adding that after the `RUN apt-get` command