# How to install pip in a dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, pip

I need to run a python program on a fairly short deadline. The program is wrapped as a docker app. I honestly never heard of Docker until yesterday. I watched some tutorials and read some blogs and tried to get up to speed.

Here is the code I need to run:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
WORKDIR /chime_sims
RUN conda update -yq -n base -c defaults conda
RUN conda create -yq -n chime_sims python=3.7 pip pandas matplotlib scipy numpy seaborn
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -q -r requirements.txt
```

When I ran it, I got an error that pip was not recognized. I looked into it and came across an answer on Stack overflow stating that I need to first install pip. So I added another line of code:

```
RUN apt-get install python-pip
```

At first when the code would run in Terminal it would run without the line that I added, even though I saved the file. I would still get the same error that pip was not recognized. Then I stopped getting that error and I started getting this:

failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend
dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount461015860/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

I tried restarting Docker, but that didn't help. I would appreciate any help with this.

Thank you,

Comment: what is the name of your file?, the error is because of the file name mismatching.

Comment: `pip` is already installed as you can see if you do `docker run continuumio/miniconda3 pip --version`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611052/install-pip-in-docker