# Can't set proxy in dockerfile

Tags: docker, proxy, firewall

I cannot run the Docker ["Getting started" example](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) behind a corporate firewall. It runs fine at home without the firewall.

When I build the image using `docker build -t my_tag .`, it fails when trying to install some python packages. The docker file has this command:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The error message is:

> Collecting Redis (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after
>   connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))': /simple/redis/

I have tried setting the proxy in the dockerfile (in various formats, but they all fail):

```
ENV http_proxy http://my_username:my_password@my_host:/80
ENV https_proxy https://my_username:my_password@my_host:/80
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://my_username:my_password@my_host:/80
ENV HTTPS_PROXY https://my_username:my_password@my_host:/80
ENV http_proxy http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV https_proxy https://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV HTTPS_PROXY https://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV http_proxy=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV https_proxy=https://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV HTTP_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=https://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
```

I have tried setting the environment in the file /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80/" "HTTPS_PROXY=https://my_username:my_password@my_host:80/"
```

I have tried changing the `RUN pip install` command in the dockerfile so it includes the proxy also:

```
RUN pip install --proxy="my_username:my_password@my_host:80" -r requirements.txt
```

I have tried setting the options in /etc/default/docker, adding:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"
```

I have tried adding the proxy to the docker build command:

```
docker build -t python_example_1 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=https://my_username:my_password@my_host:80 --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80 .
```

I am running this on Linux mint with docker version 1.12.6.

Anyone have any ideas?

---

Update 1:
If I simplify the dockerfile so it uses curl (no python or pip)

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV http_proxy=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV https_proxy=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV HTTP_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80

RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl

CMD ["curl www.google.com.au"]
```

the error message indicates it is getting the proxy info, but there is some sort of name resolution problem:

```
Removing intermediate container 945f8123da61
Step 10 : RUN apt-get -qq update
 ---> Running in 99a5bbbb943d
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'my_host'
```

where "my_host" is the correct proxy (BTW I have tested this and the username/password/proxy hostname do work)

---

Update 2
If I remove ENV from the docker file, so it is now:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
EXPOSE 80

ARG http_proxy=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ARG https_proxy=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ARG HTTP_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80
ARG HTTPS_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80

RUN apt-get -qq update
```

and build using --build-args:

```
docker build --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80 --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80 .
```

the error is still `Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'`

If I try to add a nameserver by putting this in the docker file:

```
RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
RUN cat /etc/resolve.conf
```

the error message is:

```
cat: /etc/resolve.conf: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c cat /etc/resolve.conf' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Maybe that doesn't work because it is creating the /etc/resolv.conf file in an "intermediate container" which is not available in the next step?. The longer output is:

```
Removing intermediate container 1f77c03ee8be
Step 5 : RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in e2a9717f6bed
 ---> 13752a04094b
Removing intermediate container e2a9717f6bed
Step 6 : RUN cat /etc/resolve.conf
 ---> Running in 94ce4a72867b
cat: /etc/resolve.conf: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a proxy set in your normal environment (meaning no in a docker build, but for your host OS), double-check its `https_proxy` value.

An `https_proxy` URL should be the same as an `http_proxy` one: it should start with `http`.
*Not* `https`.

Do first a simple test in a simplified Dockerfile (`curl www.google.com` for instance)
Then, see also [pip issue  1805](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1805#issuecomment-332149545) which shows how `pip` can use a proxy.

Comment: Thanks VonC  alkfdla alkdj

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I was trying to update my question with your suggestion to try curl. I have tried curl and editted my question with the update (not sure if this the right way to do it - I couldn't see how to "reply" to your suggestion.

Comment: @John By suggesting `curl www.google.com.au` I didn't mean CMD, but a simple RUN, to see the output during the build. Actually, your `apt-get -qq update` alone is a good test: as long as it is not working, nothing else internet-related will.

Comment: @John Try and remove your ENV lines, add two ARG (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) lines: `ARG http_proxy` and `ARG https_proxy`. Then `docker build` with the `--build-args` parameters (and the `https_proxy` using an http URL)

Comment: Using --build-args doesn't help. I also tried setting the name server. Please see my Update 2 above

Comment: @John Just to be sure and to check: does a docker search hello-world is working? DO you still have an HTTPS_PROXY variable starting with https instead of http in your `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`? Did you restart the docker service after modifying that file? (or did you reboot?)

Comment: Yes, "docker run hello-world" works fine. My http-proxy.conf file contains `[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:80"` Since inserting those settings, I have restarted using `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add DNS entries to /etc/docker/daemon.json.

See [the description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991136/docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-a)