# Issue building docker image: Unable to locate package / command returns non-zero code 100

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am new to Docker.
I used the following command to build an image but I get errors:

```
sudo docker build -t docker-custom-app .
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
apt-get install -y curl &&\
apt-get install -y python3 &&\
apt-get install -y python3-pip &&\
pip install flask &&\
pip install flask-mysql

COPY . /opt/source-code

ENTRYPOINT FLASK_APP=/opt/source-code/app.py flask run
```

The error I get:

E: Unable to locate package curl
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&apt-get install -y curl &&apt-get install -y python3 &&apt-get install -y python3-pip &&pip install flask &&pip install flask-mysql' returned a non-zero code: 100

even if I use another RUN command, e.g.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&\
pip install flask &&\
pip install flask-mysql
```

I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h3Cw.png

E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&pip install flask &&pip install flask-mysql' returned a non-zero code: 100

Or another RUN command example:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
apt-get install -y python3 &&\
apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&\
pip install flask &&\
pip install flask-mysql
```

I get an error:

E: Unable to locate package python3
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&apt-get install -y python3 &&apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&pip install flask &&pip install flask-mysql' returned a non-zero code: 100

I always get an error something like *Unable to locate package/returned a non-zero code:100*

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have included a link to a PNG file in place of the error message.  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual error message?  For layer-caching reasons you generally need to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single command; do collapsing all of the `RUN` commands together improve things any?

Comment: Hello David! Thanks for helping.
I have edited Dockerfile, but I get the same error.

Comment: your error in the image does not match the dockerfile you wrote, why is that?

Comment: Hello Aking! This is because the RUN command I used before editing the Dockerfile is:

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&\
pip install flask &&\
pip install flask-mysql

It seems that even if I use another RUN command, e.g. 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
apt-get install -y python3 &&\
apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&\
pip install flask &&\
pip install flask-mysql

I get an error like Unable to locate package/returned a non-zero code:100
In this case: E: Unable to locate package python3

Comment: Thank you all for helping.
I found the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991136/docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get update` caused the issue, it didn't work. I think your docker installation is somehow broken or you installed docker in a wrong way. Maybe you are on mac.

Comment: Hello Kesha! Thanks for helping.
 I found the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991136/docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-a

Comment: Glad to help you. I will appreciate if you accept my answer, because it correctly points to the cause of your problem. Why update fails that's another question :)