# Docker images are only in the sudo account and not connected to internet

Tags: linux, docker, networking, build, authority

I am currently using ubuntu 22.04.

I'm trying to build a docker image.

However, I got some problems when running the following command:

```
$ docker build -t myname ./
```

The error message I received is:

```
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

I came across a solution on Stack Overflow at this URL :

[Docker build "Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'" apt-get fails to install anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991136/docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-a)

Which suggests that it might be a DNS problem.

I accepted to create '/etc/docker/daemon.json' file as recommended in the URL but couldn't resolve the issue.

So I also tried using the '--network host' method.

```
$ docker build --network host -t myname ./
```

But the result was the same.

Finally, I attempted:

```
$ sudo docker build --network host -t myname ./
```

This seemed to work, but after completing the build, I couldn‘t see the images with the following command.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
```

However, I could see the images with 'sudo':

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
myname        latest    0f94e12e6ddd   39 minutes ago   10.8GB
hello-world   latest    d2c94e258dcb   8 months ago     13.3kB
```

Even though I granted superuser authority to my user, the issue persists.

The main problem is that without 'sudo', I can't resolve the DNS problem, but with 'sudo', I cant' use Docker images without 'sudo'.

Comment: Is your user in the `docker` group? Check with the `groups` command. Also, how did you install docker?

Comment: Yes I put user in docker group.
$ getent group docker
docker:x:999:choi

When I install docker.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
I follow official install method.
After then I install docker desktop for Linux seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed docker engine and Docker Desktop for Linux at the same time; one is enough.

My recommendation is to remove Docker Desktop and stick to docker engine.

Comment: Thank you so much. I uninstall entire docker and docker-desktop and remove every configurations.
Then install again only docker-engine. Now docker is working well. Thank you very much expert of docker sir.